# SmtpClient.send "operation timed out error"

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, smtpclient

I am trying to use `SmtpClient.Send` to send emails (on Win7 OS, .NET 4.5+). The same `sendMail` code is being re-used in two different applications (lets call them App-1 and App-2). App-1 runs under Admin-1 profile while App-2 runs under Admin-2 profile. Both profiles have `administrator/highest` privileges. App-1 is supposed to send an email at 1900 Hrs whereas App-2 is supposed to send an email at 0300 Hrs.  The `From` and `To` email addresses are same for both the apps. Both `fromEmail` and `toEmail` are valid, including `fromPass`.

The problem:

- App-1 seems to be sending emails correctly albeit sometimes not all times!
- App-2 seems to throw  "Operation Timed Out" error (even after multiple attempts every 5 minutes)

The solutions I have tried until now:

1. Trawl through internet and tried what possible solutions were being proposed
2. Changing port from `587` to `465`: This does not work very well
3. performing multiple attempts to `send` assuming it was a internet problem

My AV/firewalls don't seem to be blocking any ports. My internet connection is quite stable.

Nothing seems to have worked. Why doesn't it work? Hopefully it is a silly mistake that I have overlooked!  `sendMail` code is provided below if someone can throw some light on this it will be helpful. (`Utils.doProcessLog` is my process-logger)

**Update:** I realised that if I re-start the application, the emails are sent correctly during the first run and then for the subsequent runs it throws "Operation timed out" error

**Update-2:** I created a plain windows-form application with `Email` button that calls the `sendEmail` function. The application works correctly (i.e. sends email) whenever I press the button.

**Update-3**  One of the pdf-reports is 900KB and the other is 1.72MB. The `sendMail` appears to crash only on the pdf-report that is 1.72MB. There appears to be a known bug for attachments over 3MB, so 1.72MB should not be a problem but it does not work for me. I am unable to install this hotfix (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2183292) as the installation says "this hotfix is not applicable to you". I have tried the work-around suggested in that Microsoft-hotfix link and I still get the error.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
'%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
' SEND EMAIL
'%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Public Function sendMail(ByVal Subject As String) As Boolean

    Dim fl As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim good As Boolean
    ' for EMAILS
    Const mailStrAddress = "fromEmail@gmail.com"
    Const mailStrPass = "fromPass"
    Const mailStrHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Const mailToAdd = "toEmail@gmail.com"
    Const maxAttempt = 5

    ' Subject & Body
    Dim st = "This is a report generated from " & ThisWorkbook.Name
    Dim subj = ThisWorkbook.Name & ": " & Subject
    If IsNothing(subj) Then
        subj = "CAUTION: EMPTY STRING"
    End If

    Utils.doProcessLog("about to email reports")
    good = False

    For i = 0 To maxAttempt
        '
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
        '
        Try
            mail.From = New MailAddress(mailStrAddress) ' Email address
            ' The important part -- configuring the SMTP client
            smtp.Port = 587   ' [1] You can try with 465 also, I always used 587 and got success
            smtp.EnableSsl = True
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network ' [2] Added this
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False ' [3] Changed this
            smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(mailStrAddress, mailStrPass)  ' password-here [4] Added this. Note, first parameter is NOT string.
            smtp.Host = mailStrHost
            smtp.Timeout = 100000  ' 100 seconds
            ' recipient address
            mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(mailToAdd))
            ' Formatted mail body
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

            mail.Subject = subj
            mail.Body = st
            ' Send
            smtp.Send(mail)
            '
            Utils.doProcessLog("report emailed")
            good = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Utils.doProcessLog("unable to email report : " & ex.Message)
            Utils.doProcessLog("waiting for 5 minutes before re-trying :" & CStr(i))
            good = False
            Utils.doWait(5 * 60 * 1000)  ' = 5(min)*60(secs)*1000(ms)

        Finally
            '
            mail.Dispose()
            smtp.Dispose()
            '
        End Try
        ' exit if successful
        If good Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I have also encountered the same problem. I think the problem lies with the smtp server instead. It is unlikely the codes that are causing it.

Comment: @Hatjhie, what do mean by "problem lies with the smtp server"? do you mean smtp.gmail.com has problems at it's end?

Comment: @Hatjhie, You mentioned that you are facing the same problem. Are you using something totally different to overcome this problem?

Comment: Nope. In my environment, we do not use smtp.gmail.com, we use our own. The problem is still existed, and it's pending the smtp server admin to investigate and fine tune, cause the problem is really not caused by the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toiling with this problem for over a month, I think I have a solution to my problem.

The 900KB pdf was being emailed correctly, while the emailing the 1.72MB file was throwing a `operation timed out error`. After letting the system run many times over, I noticed that if the pdf was around 1MB the emails were being sent correctly. So, the size of the pdf was causing a problem. When I looked at my own process logs, I realised that the `stmpclient.send` was being called and the exception was being thrown after around 1 min 30secs (100 seconds). So based on this, I concluded that attaching and emailing a file greater than 1MB might require more than 100seconds, so increased my `smtpclient.timeout` from 100seconds to 500seconds. It has run couple of times and it is emailing the reports correctly, hopefully this has fixed my bug!